# I get error 400 with instabot api in python

Tags: python, instagram

Currently I want to generate a bot for instagram which should follow people from another account automatically but I get an error: I get error 400 with the instabot api in python.

Code Python:

```
# importar la clase a utilizar
from instabot import Bot
# crear el nuevo objeto
mi_bot = Bot()
mi_bot.login(username='xxxxxxxx', password='xxxxxxxxx')
mi_bot.follow_followers('xxxxxxxx')
```

I execute it on the cmd as follows.

```
python main.py
```

and the error that comes out is the following:

```
2020-02-20 17:23:10,742 - instabot version: 0.107.0 (bot) - INFO - Instabot version: 0.107.0 Started
2020-02-20 17:23:10,773 - instabot version: 0.107.0 (api_login) - INFO - PRE-LOGIN FLOW!... 
2020-02-20 17:23:22,801 - instabot version: 0.107.0 (api) - ERROR - Request returns 400 error!
2020-02-20 17:23:22,801 - instabot version: 0.107.0 (api) - INFO - Instagram's error message: challenge_required
2020-02-20 17:23:22,801 - instabot version: 0.107.0 (api) - INFO - Error type: checkpoint_challenge_required
2020-02-20 17:23:22,801 - instabot version: 0.107.0 (api) - INFO - Checkpoint challenge required...
2020-02-20 17:23:22,816 - instabot version: 0.107.0 (bot_follow) - INFO - Follow followers of: xxxxxxxxxxxx
2020-02-20 17:23:22,816 - instabot version: 0.107.0 (api) - CRITICAL - Not logged in!
```

The version of python I use is 3.8.1, which I understand is the most recent.

Comment: `The version of python I use is 3.8.1, which I understand is the most recent` uh no sorry 3.10 is the newest, but idk if that affects your program